# Which Philosophers Wrote Directly About Education?

Tags: reference-request, education

I assume the list is short, so can someone please list which philosophers (not pure educationalists) wrote entire books or treatises dedicated to education? I can name a few, for example, John Dewey's *Experience and Education*, John Locke's *Some Thoughts Concerning Education*, and Rousseau's *Emile*.

Thanks

Comment: See [Philosopy of Education](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/education-philosophy/)

Comment: Pretty sure the list isn't short. After all, it starts at least as early as Socrates and goes on to include philosophers currently alive.

Comment: Top of head...Plato (Republic, Meno, etc.), Montaigne, Rousseau (Emile), Diderot, John Dewey...but really, many, I'm sure. Dewey is probably the biggest name most directly linked to work on education.

Comment: Read John Taylor Gatto's book Underground History of American Education. It's full with quotations from best and most influential educators and thinkers in general.

Comment: Bert Russell wrote several essays and books on education.

Comment: *Agnoiology* [the study of ignorance]. For those interested, [Agnotology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnotology)

Answer (score 3):

If you meant, which philosophers wrote exclusively about education, I suspect that is none. You mentioned John Dewey, who here at the University of Chicago's lab school, is of course known for his contributions, but most philosophers cover philosophy tangentially to other works. It's a lot of work to suss out which passages from the great thinkers are applicable, but besides the SEP article Philosophy of Education Allegranza mentions in the comments, there are books devoted to this. The one I have is [The Philosophical Foundations of Education, 7th Ed (GB)](https://books.google.com/books?id=fsRKAAAAYAAJ&q=philosophical%20foundations%20of%20educations%207th&dq=philosophical%20foundations%20of%20educations%207th&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikgYWZ5oj9AhU5BzQIHUUBB4cQ6AF6BAgKEAI). I'll list the philosophers by table of contents:

1. Idealism and Education - Plato *The Republic*, Kant *Education*
2. Realism and Education - Aristotle *The Politics and Ethics of Aristotle*, Locke *Some Thoughts Concerning Education*
3. Eastern Philosophy, Religion, and Education - *Bhagavad-Gita*, Suzuki *Zen Mind, Beginner's Mind*
4. Pragmatism and Education - James *Talks to Teachers*, Dewey *Democracy and Education*
5. Reconstructionism and Education - Counts *Dare the Schools Build a New Social Order?*, Shane and Shane *Educating the Youngest for Tomorrow*
6. Behaviorism and Education - Hobbes *The Leviathan*, Skinner *Beyond Freedom and Dignity*
7. Existentialism, Phenomenology, and Education - Sartre *Existentialism and Humanism*, Greene *Landscapes of Learning*
8. Analytic Philosophy and Education - Martin *On the Reduction of "Knowing That" to "Knowing How"*, Barrow *Does the Question "What Is Education?" Make Sense?
9. Marxism and Education - Marx *On Education*
10. Philosophy, Education, and the Challenge of Postmoderinism - Giroux *Border Pedagogy as Postmodern Resistance*, Nuyen *Lyotard as Moral Educator*

To Chapter 7 I'd add Morris van Cleve *Existentialism in Education: What It Means* who was here at UIC and to Chapter 9 I'd add Paolo Friere *Pedagogy of the Oppressed* which is critical theoretical in nature who is also very popular, at least in Chicagoland curricula. Also, there's no clear line of demarcation between philosophy of education and a [naturalized epistemology (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemology-naturalized/) refering to educational psychology, so any work by Jean Piaget and Lev Vygotsky are a must.

The book I reference does have additional pointers to passages and works not listed in the table of contents. For instance, just flipping through A.N. Whitehead, a contemporary of Russell wrote a very brief *Aims of Education* (Almost as short as Dewey's *Democracy and Education*) and some work by Richard Rorty. And there are other textbooks that conduct comparable surveys.

Answer (score 1):

- [Johann Friedrich Herbart](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/johann-herbart/), [Science of Education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_of_Education_(book)).
- [Johann Gottlieb Fichte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Gottlieb_Fichte), [Addresses to the German Nation](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Addresses_to_the_German_Nation).

Answer (score 1):

- **Plato, *The Meno*** (esp. the excerpt in Deely, [*Four Ages of Understanding*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4151), p[p. 45](https://books.google.com/books?id=zAsjkHJ8aP8C&pg=PA45)-52)
- **St. Augustine, *De Magistro*** (ch. 2.2 of Mooney & Nowacki, [*Understanding Teaching & Learning*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4202))
- **St. Thomas Aquinas, *De Magistro*** ([*De veritate* q. 11](https://isidore.co/aquinas/QDdeVer11.htm); [*ibid.*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4202) ch. 3.2)
- **John Henry Newman**, [*The Idea of a University*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8693) (cf., e.g., [Discourse 5. Knowledge its Own End](https://www.newmanreader.org/works/idea/discourse5.html); [*ibid.*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4202) ch. 4.2)